# What is the origin of Shukracharya gotra?

Tags: gotra, shukracharya

When I asked my parents, what is our gotra, they told me **Shukracharya** is our gotra. I tried searching over the internet but could not find about Shukracharya gotra. It is not present [under the list of gotra on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gotras).

What is the origin of Shukracharya gotra? 
Is it related to [Shukracharya, the Guru of Asuras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shukra)?

Comment: What's your caste? I have read that different castes have different list of gotras.

Comment: My Caste is Sonar. I'm Gujraati and Surname is Jogiya

Comment: **Kuldevi**: Hingulambika
**Vansha**: Manu
Found Some Info about shukracharya here 
[link](http://www.bhavsarsamaj.com/gotra-list/shukracharya)

Answer (score 3):

Sriguru Shukraacharya was from the lineage of Great Maharshi Bhrigu. Hence he was called "bhArgava". Bhargava pravara is related to many gotras. I am posting the gotras which have bhargava pravara so that it can help you in finding the right gotra. Bold are the gotras and next to them are the pravara. Most probably the first one would be your gotra. But please verify the information from elders before accepting it.

**Bhargava**: Bhargava ,Tvashta,Vishvarupa

**Jamadagni**: Bhargava, Chyavana, Aapnavaana, Aurava, Jaamadagneya

**Vatsa**: Orva,Bhardwaj,Bhargava, Chyavana, Aapnavan

**Vatula/Vadula**: Bhargava,Vaitahavya,Saavedasa

**Srivatsa/Vatsasya**: Bhargava,Chyaavana,Aapnavaana,Aurva,Jaamadaghneya

[Source](http://familypedia.wikia.com/wiki/Brahmin_gotra_system)

P.S: The above mentioned gotra are mostly brahmin gotra. But for non brahmin's the apt gotra would be brArgava.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll ask my family Pandit Ji too about this.

Answer (score 0):

Not much information available on this but still... Usually gotra means either you belong to that rishi's clan or your clan would have accepted him as guru/kulguru.

What I got from [here](http://brishpati.tripod.com/id20.html) is:

> SHUKRACHARYA IS SON OF MAHARISHI BRIGHU (one of the saptrishis) AND USHANA.HE WAS BORN IN YEAR PAARTHIVA ON FRIDAY ON SHRAVAN SUDHA ASHTAMI WHEN SWATI NAKASHTRA WAS ASCENDING. HIS GOTRA IS BHARGAVA.

Also referring [this](https://www.jatland.com/home/Shukra):

> Shukra (शुक्र) was the name of the son of Bhrigu, and preceptor of the Daityas, and the guru of the Asuras.

Also see [this](http://www.bhavsarsamaj.com/gotra-list/shukracharya).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This got me some info about Shukracharya, but shukracharya gotra I don't understand.

Comment: @VishalJ I gues Mr.Joshi's answer was more helpful:)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know much more about Shukracharya. I just knew He was Guru of Asura. Now I know bit more.